# PropertyGrid for Windows 8 Store Apps (WinRT/XAML)

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml

I need a *PropertyGrid* control (like implemented in Windows Forms or in WPF) **but** for *Windows 8 Store Apps* only? Will you recommend any available free or commercial PropertyGrid control for *WinRT/XAML*? 
Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with the one from WPF?

Comment: Windows 8 Store App is based on WinRT, not WPF layer. Can I use (host) an existing WPF PropertyGrid in Store App?

Comment: Not an answer, but the classic property grid isn't a very suitable interface for a touch-first experience - what type of information are you trying to present? Might it be more appropriate for the settings flyout?

Comment: Suppose I have a set of 50 C# classes, one root class and other derived from it in two or three levels. Each class has its own (additional) properties of different types (int, double, bool, enums, etc.). All I want is to be able to modify those properties in one panel. As I understand, when using the settings flyout, I should create such a flyout for **each** class type. However, this approach is ‘straightforward’ and is not convenient. I thing, the better solution is to use PropertyGrid, which supports touching but probably with bigger (two or three times) height of its items… for fingers :)

Answer (score -3):

When you create a Windows Store App you'll can create it either using HTML5/JavaScript or C++,C# and VB.NET with WPF/XAML. 
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx) for further reference.